# Can't Import MASM Function Into C

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, linker, masm, masm32

Using VS2019 (32-Bit Project)

What I tried:

- Enabling '.masm' in 'Build Customizations'
- Setting the '.asm' file's type as 'Microsoft Macro Assembler'
- Setting 'Preserve Identifier Case' to '/Cp' - 'Preserves Identifier Case'
- Putting a `PUBLIC *My function's name* both before, after my function and at the top
- Setting 'Mark All Symbols Public' to 'Yes'
- Adding/Removing underscores from my function's name in the '.asm' file as well as from the 'extern' definition inside the '.c' file.
- Putting the definition inside a '.h' file.

Nothing seems to work, I keep getting the LNK2001 error.

Here is how I am doing it (With the actual assembly code removed, since it happens regardless of it):

Assembly file:

```
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
.code

MyFunction proc
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
mov eax,[ebp+08h]
;...
pop ebp
ret 04h
MyFunction endp

end
```

C file:

```
extern void __stdcall MyFunction(unsigned int x);
```

Comment: Did you 3nwble build customizations before or after you added the asm files. If after you have to ensure the files are marked to be part of the build.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I have verified it's not exluded from build and the log mentions "Assembling File.asm..."

Comment: Show us the linker error you get with the sp3cific options you are using now.

Comment: @MichaelPetch https://i.imgur.com/iXd1kOj.png I should mention there's an underline at the beginning there but my function does not have one. I did try to add one in both the .asm and .c file though just to see but it did not work, of course.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using recall instead of cdecl. With stdcall  you may have to do name decorations.

Comment: I have verified that making it a __cdecl and changing .model flat,stdcall to .model flat,c fixes my issue. How could I get it to work with an __stdcall? Also would you happen to know why the name decoration thing with __stdcall? Doesn't make much sense

Comment: I checked out MSDN and tried both adding an underscore and placing a @*size of all parameters as decimal), basically the name the linker error was complaining about, and it does not work (This is in the .asm file).

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed my issue.

It seems that in my case the fact that I did not decorate the instruction was not an issue, the issue was that MASM would not know how many parameters my function had so it the decorated symbol was `_MyFunctionName@0`.

I first added a prototype with parameters to my function as such:
`MyFunction proc stdcall x:DWORD`

But then the problem was that MASM would generate its own prologue and epilogue for my function which would screw up the stack so I additionally added the following lines at the top of my file:

```
option prologue:none
option epilogue:none
```

And it now works perfectly.